# Determining a lower bound on the order of a group based on its presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I am reading Abstract Algebra book by Dummit and Foote (3-rd edition).

On pages 26-27 they define a dihedral group:

$D_{2n} = \langle r,s | r^n = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$

The authors describe a group (a regular n-gon's rotations, where $r$ is $\frac{2\cdot\Pi}{n}$ rotation and $s$ is a flip) which satisfies this representation.

Then they claim that, based on the existance of such a group, any group with such a representation must have an order of **at least 2n**. Why is it so? Is there any theorem from which they derive the claim?

Comment: Can't you just explicitly enumerate the elements of $D_{2n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $G_{2n}$ as the subgroup of orthogonal transformations (rotations, flip etc.), it is not hard to see that this group has indeed $2n$ elements, and that it is a homomorphic image of $D_{2n}$. (Given where the remark is in the book, this argument of homomorphic image is not entirely kosher.)
Thus the order of $D_{2n}$ needs to be at least equal to the order of $G_{2n}$.

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with the term "homomorphic image" with respect to a presentation. I guess I need to read more about group presentations and this term. You confirmed my suspicion that the book puts the cart before the horse in this remark:)